# How to login through the public API authentication process for a web application?

Tags: php, web-services, api, authentication, web-applications

I have set up a web server and the next step is to create a login page with any languages or technology.
The login page should contain a single button- "Login with COMPANY". When the user clicks login, they should be directed through the COMPANY public API authentication process for a web application. My web application should maintain the user's API credentials within a session. Any help or reference to any resources will be appreciated.
I wondered if I should use a plugin or I should write a php program myself which is connecting to the COMPANY's website. I know very basic about PHP and HTML. If you know any example such as google or facebook will be appreciated. For instance where you have a web server and your user is logging in through your website its facebook account. Similar to what we do in stackoverflow. We can log in by facebook account or google account.

Answer (score 1):

So many APIs are there which can solve your problem like:-

1]SoundCloud API `http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs`
2]SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) Service for Google Apps `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation`
3]OAuth `https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/`

Check these links

Answer (score 1):

Signin with other application is not tough job. You just need to maintain Web Server session / token in your system.

Normally what FB and other sites are doing, when you try to login they will provide you one token in response as proof that, this credential and user is correct. Using that token you need to create one more session that will be your local_token to give access to internal site.

It's might possible that after sometime, FB will expire your token. So if your local_token is expired then you need to relogin with system.

Also make sure your web server token should keep change for each login attempt.

Hope that helps !!!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout with some example that give you some idea how to create API server.

1. [Facebook SDK - Support login with Facebook - With example](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk)
2. [GitHub SDK - Support login with GitHub](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)

Regards